# Angular ng-repeat without creating an element

Tags: html, angularjs, html-lists, angularjs-ng-repeat

Suppose I have this `Json` data in my `controller`:

```
var rootObj = [{
    devices: ["device1", "device2"],
    subGroups: [{devices: ["device3", "device4"]}, {devices: ["device5", "device6"]}]
}, {
    devices: ["device7"],
    subGroups: [{devices: ["device8"]}, {devices: ["device9"]}]
}];
```

And I want to show all devices in flat structure, like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>device1</li>
    <li>device2</li>
    <li>device3</li>
    <li>device4</li>
    <li>device5</li>
    <li>device6</li>
    <li>device7</li>
    <li>device8</li>
    <li>device9</li>
</ul>
```

How can I use `ng-repeat` on `rootObj`to get above html?
I **don't** want to manipulate the original object, only using `ng-repeat` on `rootObj`.

The only option to solve it, is to use `ng-repeat` **without** creating any element on ng-repeat itself.

What is the best way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

It achievable with [black magic](https://lodash.com/docs#flattenDeep)!

> Returns
>   (Array): Returns the new flattened array.

Comment: "I don't want to manipulate the original object, only using ng-repeaton rootObj"

Comment: So you either do not want to use filter I guess